# Need to extract Live Goals and Time Left data from "https://sports.williamhill.com/betting/en-gb/in-play/football"

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

Got response of website using requests get , but i am unable to find the live time left and goals of both teams.
If you inspect element on the website you will find the live data in 'label' tag under class 'wh-label btmarket__live go area-livescore event__status'

Please Help me , how can i get the data .

Hit Website with Python Requests and converted to Soup and doesn't contain live timer data

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://sports.williamhill.com/betting/en-gb/in-play/football"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
print(soup.prettify)
```

Comment: It's because the dynamic elements on the page are being rendered with JavaScript, not raw HTML. You will have to decompose their JavaScript imports or use a headless browser like Selenium to access dynamic elements like that.

Comment: can you guide me more on decompose their javascript? Also, Selenium will be the last option since it is very slow method .

Comment: can't access the site (as it's blocked by my firewall, so could check later). But the 3 options you have: 1) Selenium (but I know you don't want to use it); 2) see if the data is requested through api endpoint, which if is the case, you can get the data straight from that source, or 3) as the comment above said, find the data with the `<script>` tags (if it's there), then manipulate that into a valid json format to then use `json.loads()` to read that in.